# infinite limit question from Calc I

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, infinity, radicals

Find the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x$$

This limit is part of a question involving squeeze theorum, the limit is $\frac12$ but i don't know how to prove it because of the polynomial in the radial, any help in apprechiated!

Comment: did you try multiplying by the conjugate over the conjugate?  Ie $\frac {\sqrt {x^2+x+1}+x} {\sqrt {x^2+x+1}+x}$

Comment: i have i didnt help because there is still a radical in the denominator

Comment: But you get it to the form of $\frac \infty \infty$, so you can use L'hospitals, no? (I haven't worked it out, just eyeballed it)

Comment: After you have done the conjugat trick, divide top and bottom by $x$.

Comment: Or that, which is simpler :).

Comment: i could solve it that way but this is for my math written assignment and they haven't taught us L'hospitals rule in class yet so we are not allowed to use it

Comment: Andre's method (Which is explained below in two answers) does it without L'hospitals

Comment: thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\eqalign{\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x} \\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+x+1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+1/x}{\sqrt{1+1/x+1/x^2}+1}\\&=\frac12.}$$

Comment: thanks i didnt know you could change the radical like that

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}= \\ =\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2+x+1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$